# set permissions on a directory by active directory organizational units

Tags: active-directory, permissions, network-share

I would like to set permissions on a directory (or/and share) by active directory organizational units instead of users groups. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can create a script that runs everyday to populate groups membership based on the organizational units, and use the groups to grant access.